# Migrating Rails app from SQLite3 to Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

I'm attempting to migrate the database of my Rails app from SQLite3 to Postgresql , but not finding this at all easy. I'm following this Railscast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql).

I've edited my database.yml file to the following:

```
default: &default
 adapter: postgresql
 pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
 timeout: 5000

development:
 <<: *default
 database: db/development.postgresql

test:
 <<: *default
 database: db/test.postgresql

production:
 <<: *default
 database: db/production.postgresql
```

All I did here was to change all parts that said 'SQLite3' to 'postgresql'. This was not the same as the Railscast, but I guessed that it was outdated (2012).

I had already installed gem 'pg', '~> 0.21.0', and I removed the SQLite3 gem. I already have Postgresql 9.6.3 installed.

Next I installed the taps gem (0.3.24). After this I tried 'rake db:create:all' but the error message returned is the following:

```
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "pool"=>5, 
"timeout"=>5000, "database"=>"db/development.postgresql"}
rake aborted!
```

I read in this website that I may need to do a Heroku migration - 'heroku run rake db:migrate', but when I try this the same error is returned.

I don't really know what this error message means - I think it may be something to do with the conf_hba file or pgAdmin, but I don't understand how these work either.

Help would be much appreciated, thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to supply `password` & `username` of your postgres db in your file as 
`

```
default: &default
    adapter: postgresql
    encoding: unicode
    pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
    timeout: 5000
```

development:
    <<: *default
    database: performance_rails_develop
    username: postgres
    password: password
    pool: 5

test:
    <<: *default
    database: performance_rails_test
    username: postgres
    password: password

production:
    <<: *default
    database: db/production.sqlite3
`

Comment: Do you mean that you simply enter a username and password of your own choosing on your database.yml file?

Comment: No @Robert this username & password are the database username & password.

Comment: sorry, I'm fairly new to this game. How would I find out my database username & password?

Comment: ok no problem, Chek [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/110154/whats-the-default-superuser-username-password-for-postgres-after-a-new-install) out.

Comment: Doesn't make it any clearer unfortunately. I keep being asked for a password that I don't know, and there is no way of setting a new one :-(

Comment: @Robert I always use [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-postgresql-on-ubuntu-16-04) documentation for installation of Postgres , there are post-installation steps I would like to take a look at.